# How to create memory leaks on Java Web?

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, struts2, out-of-memory

I attended an interview in which I was asked 'How to create memory leak using Struts2?'
but I did not have a clue. As I know I can create it using static fields or not closing the DB connection etc but did not have a clue how to create it specifically with Struts2.

I could find following which might be related to the question.

> - Areas that are unreachable from JVM's garbage collector
> - like memory allocated through native methods
> - In web applications objects stored in application scope till application is restarted or removed explicitly

Comment: @Hirak knowing how to create memory leaks means you know how to avoid/fix them